# Are the Russian word "чары" and English word "charm" etymologically related?

Tags: этимология

Do "чары" and "charm" share a common etymological root?

According to the OED, "charm" originates (through French) from Latin 
*carmen* ("song"), which is believed to originate from the Proto-Indo-European verb **keh₂n-* ("to sing").

And according Wiktionary, "чары" is from "Proto-Slavic **čarъ*, from Proto-Balto-Slavic **ker- *kēr-*, from Proto-Indo-European **kʷer-*.

Despite this, the similarities in sound and meaning of the two words seems too great to just be a coincidence...does anyone have any other info about their origin and possible etymological links?

Comment: There are several hundred thousand words in English and in Russian, so coincidences like this are bound to happen, merely by statistical reasons. Consider English "have" and Latin _habeo_, English "bad" and Persian _bæd_, Russian _бяка_ and Japanese _baka_, etc.

Comment: Any other info will necessarily be less credible.

I know the feeling that it just seems like a *waste* when two words in different languages are close in sound and meaning, and yet are unrelated. I feel it's important to let go of that emotional attachment to interesting explanations and accept that sometimes comparative linguistics can feel frustratingly messy and random.

Comment: this is rather a question for linguistics SE to be honest.

Answer (score 4):

Чары`Этимологический словарь русского языка`
чары Общеслав. Того же корня, что авест. čārā «средство», др.-инд. karóti «делает», лит. keraĩ «волшебство». Колдовство воспринималось как средство для достижения какой-л. цели. Школьный этимологический словарь русского языка. Происхождение слов. — М.: Дрофа Н. М. Шанский, Т. А. Боброва 2004

The later academician Zaliznyak stated that quantity of sounds was more restricted than quantity of words, thus, there was lots of coincidence, and it was a subject of quasi-scientific speculations.

I believe, we shouldn't make conclusions based upon homophony without a deep research.

If you feel like watching Zaliznyak's speech on this topic (not charm, but quasi-theories in linguistics), you are welcome. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rP3UyDow5i4